# Function satisfying $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}(f(x)-f(2x))$ but doesn't have $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}f(x)$

Tags: calculus

I want to find a function that does not have a limit as  $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}f(x)$, but the following limit does exist: $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}(f(x)-f(2x))$.

Any direction or hint would be appreciated.

Comment: I guess $f(x)=sgn(x)$ would do the job. That is $f$ equals $1$, $0$ or $-1$ when $x$ is positive, null or negative, respectively.

Comment: Does $\pm\infty$ count as existence of the limit?

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=\chi_{{\bf{Q}}}(x)$, then $f(2x)=\chi_{{\bf{Q}}}(2x)=\chi_{{\bf{Q}}}(x)=f(x)$ but $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x)$ does not exist.

Comment: What is $\chi_{{\bf{Q}}}$?

Comment: The function takes the value $1$ for all rational numbers and $0$ otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Take

$f(x)=\ln(x)$

$f(2x)=\ln(2x)=\ln(2)+\ln(x)$

$g(x)=f(x)-f(2x)=-\ln(2)$

Here $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)$ is undefined but $f(x)-f(2x)$ is a constant

Comment: Btw, if you consider $\pm\infty$ to be a limit then consider $f(x)=\Im(\ln(ix))=\arg(ix)=\arg(i2x)=\Im(\ln(i2x))=f(2x)\implies f(x)-f(2x)=0\forall x$ and $lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)=\pi/2,lim_{x\to0^-}f(x)=-\pi/2$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.** Take a function such that $$f(x)-f(2x)=f\left(\frac{x}{2x} \right)=f\left(\frac 1 2 \right)$$ You already know one of such functions  I hope.

Answer (score 0):

Any function such that $f(x)=f(2x)$ will work. Also if they differ in a constant, or if they differ in a function which is continuous at $x=0$ (but of course, that's almost rephrasing your question).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that is rather continuous.

Take $f(x) = \sin\left(2\pi\frac{\ln |x|}{\ln 2}\right)$ defined for $x \neq 0$ (you can set $f(0)=0$ if you want $f$ to be definied for all $x \in \mathbb R$). Then
$$f(2x) = \sin\left(2\pi\frac{\ln |2x|}{\ln 2}\right) = \sin\left(2\pi\frac{\ln2 + \ln |x|}{\ln 2}\right) \\= \sin\left(2\pi+2\pi\frac{\ln |x|}{\ln 2}\right) = \sin\left(2\pi\frac{\ln |x|}{\ln 2}\right) \\= f(x)$$
so
$$\lim_{x\to 0}(f(x)-f(2x)) = 0.$$
But $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)$ is not defined since $f$ oscillates quickly as $x \to 0$.